# How to avoid DLL Hijacking by using Windows unit

Tags: security, dll, vcl, delphi

I developed a Win32 app which calls Win API that uses "Windows" unit. And I believe this will call Window's system libraries such as kernel32.dll, versions.dll, etc.

But the security reviewer said there is a security issue related to preload DLL hijack and we need to implement following articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-security

My question, since we are using "Windows" unit from VCL framework, any clue on how to implement as mentioned in the above article?

Comment: I understand that too. But they insist to implement as the link above. How to explain it to them as the security reviewer doesn't know about Delphi. Any advice?

Comment: That is not related to static or dynamic linking, but to Load-Time vs. Run-Time Dynamic Linking. This rules out specifying a qualified path or any LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH flag as well as changing any system settings from inside the program. This can probably only be solved by a system administrator.

Comment: The article is about applications using [runtime dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking) (LoadLibrary). The Windows unit is using [loadtime dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking), for which the search order is controlled by the OS. SafeDllSearchMode is enabled by default.

Comment: Indeed. Nothing to see here, move along .....

Comment: Those are all known dlls anyway, the OS will not search them. My advice is to have the reviewer in some training course.

Comment: The security reviewer did prove of concept of DLL hijacking by pasting a hijacked version.dll file into the same folder as our .exe file, and our app run executed that hijacked version.dll.

Based on that POC, they declared that our app need to be patched on the article above. As we are using standard Win API/windows basic DLL, I also don't think the link above is applicable. Any advice?

Comment: Loading from the same directory is [controlled by the OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications), too. Normally a trusted installer is used to install executables into directories with restricted access.

Comment: If it's possible to access the folder that the executable is in, why would you care with dll hijacking, just replace the executable with a malicious one.

Comment: After some discussion, I think the conclusion is:
1. Make sure the SetDLLDirectory set to empty string ('') to remove current directory from standard search path.

2. Make sure Safe Search Mode by using SetSearchPathMode() function.

3. For Windows System DLL, nothing we can do from Delphi side since it is Load-Time Dynamic Link.Just need to secure my app installation folder so it won't have any unauthorized DLL files, secure our own DLL files by checking the cheksum of all included DLL files. And make sure the DLL load priority is safe.

Hope this sufficient enough..

Comment: You can see my answer on similer question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604758/how-do-i-avoid-dll-hijacking-in-delphi-application-that-uses-winapi-windows/76865256#76865256