# How do I avoid dll hijacking in Delphi application that uses WinApi.Windows

Tags: security, delphi, dll-injection

Delphi up to latest versions uses static linking of various system dlls (f.e. version.dll in unit WinApi.Windows).
That leads to loading of version.dll even before units initialization.
That opens a security hole that can be used by putting infected version.dll beside the application.

I could close the hole by safe preloading of version.dll.
The problem is - I see no any Delphi native way to do the preloading before that static linked loading.

**Update 2022-09-06**: My goal is to avoid execution of not my code from application signed by my cert.

**Update 2022-09-07**: I just found that my question is in fact a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024172/how-to-avoid-dll-hijacking-by-using-windows-unit)

Comment: If you can put infected dlls all gside the exe file, you can just change the exe file.

Comment: In case of changing my exe it will not be properly signed by my certificate anymore.

Comment: Have you tried [https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/DelayedLoading_(Delphi)] DelayedLoading yet?

Comment: What means have you got to stop the user running executables that aren't signed by you

Comment: That's not DLL **injection** (forcing a running process to load a DLL), but instead DLL **hijacking** (placing a DLL before the process is executed). See [How to avoid DLL Hijacking by using Windows unit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54024172/4299358) and consider at least using [SetDllDirectoryW('');](https://entwickler-ecke.de/viewtopic.php?p=615863#615863).

Comment: @AmigoJack you can't use `SetDllDirectoryW()` to avoid hijacking of DLLs that are loaded statically at process creation, since user code hasn't started running yet at that point. It only works for DLLs that are loaded dynamically via `LoadLibrary()` in user code, or delay-loaded by the RTL. But that still doesn't avoid hijacking if the hijacker has access to the folder you are loading your DLLs from. To truly avoid hijacking, you would have to sign your DLLs and verify them before using them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I cannot stop user to run it. But in that case attack will not be signed by my cert. My goal is to avoid execution not my code from application signed by my cert.

Comment: @USauter That is not for current case. See Remy's answer for details.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yeah that is hijacking. Updated question. But SetDllDirectory doesn't help in this case. See Remy's answer for details.

Comment: Why invest time in defending against such an attack when the attacker can trivially defeat it by replacing your exe file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because you can execute code from a trusted process, one that will not raise any alerts in monitoring and runs clean through a malware scan. Potentially the parent process is also signed making it ideal for abuse

Comment: That said, not much you can do about this one (and there are/will be more) other than secure your program folder with admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

To close static loading side DLLs security hole you can use side by side assembly loading  provided by Windows, using manifest files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/manifest)
In Delphi you can specific a custom manifest file and linker will embed it into exe.

1. **Create an Assembly Manifest:**

create a file named **.manifest** alongside your executable. This manifest will contain essential configuration details.

2. **Add File Load Configuration:**

Within the  section of the manifest, introduce:

```
<file name="version.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
```

This instruction explicitly informs Windows to load version.dll solely from the trusted system directory.

3. **Embed the Manifest:**

Open your Delphi project's options and follow screenshot
[image]

This action embeds the assembly manifest into your executable, ensuring its guidance is followed during runtime.

4. **Build and Test:**

**Build** your Delphi application to reflect the changes (Important to build not only compile).

The assembly manifest now guarantees the secure and controlled loading of version.dll from the authorized system directory.

this is full example manifest file contain all static loading dlls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    
        
    <file name="mpr.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="netapi32.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="netutils.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="textshaping.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="version.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="winhttp.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="CoreMessaging.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="DWMAPI.DLL" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="WINSTA.DLL" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="wtsapi32.DLL" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="CoreUIComponents.DLL" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />
    <file name="winspool.drv" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\system32\" />  
  
  
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application> 
  </compatibility>

</assembly>
```