# Why my exe is looking for version.dll locally?

Tags: windows, dll, exe, pascal, lazarus

I have an issue with the executable I generate in Lazarus ( I have the same problem with any project in the example folder found in Lazarus installation folder) and the windows dll version.dll. I know windows has an order https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order in which the OS search for the librarys,

I tried using the option LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH  but I fear I have to static link the library and no dinamically. How can I have my exe to look for the version.dll library only on the windows system directory?

[In the process monitor app i can see that first the dll is searched locally and then on Windows system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNQAM.png)

Comment: Why are you putting the version dll alongside your exe

Comment: It is put automatically when I create the exe file. Do you think I can remove it?

Comment: That sounds like it must be Lazarus doing that. If so, I'm not sure why. But presumably there is a reason. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? In what way does your program fail to behave as you intend?

Comment: I would like to search for version.dll only on SYS64 and not the local version. This to avoid any dll hijacking. In fact if I create an empty file version.dll locally my program first read the local one crashing.

Comment: That's how the system works and is designed. If attackers can modify the files alongside your executable, then they can modify your executable too. Why would anybody be bothered to place a fake system DLL next to your executable when they can just modify your executable? Unless you have a deep understanding of how attackers work, your attempts to defend against them won't succeed and you are just wasting your time.

Comment: Thanks I see your point. The only doubt is that if I try to build a simple exe with visual studio code in C# and the version.dll is only searched in the System directory. Maybe there are some Lazarus paramters to change that I am not able to find.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why Lazarus would place a version.dll alongside the output executable. Does it happen with a blank empty project?

Comment: It does not place a version.dll, Lazarus searches for it on the path where the executable is built instead of searching only on SYS64

Comment: And this happen with any proect found on lazarus repository under the folder example

Comment: "It is put automatically when I create the exe file".  "It does not place a version.dll." I'm confused. Did you copy version.dll next to your executable?

Comment: You have good reason to be confused, I was not clear in the first messages. I try to reformulate the problem. I am not creating or moving any version.dll file. The executable first of all search the dll in the same folder as the executable. When the dll is not found the exe looks at the system library. I would like my executable to search directly in the system library skipping the folder where the executable is launched. I hope I was more clear now.

Comment: It's not going to do what you want because the system is designed first to search for dependencies in the same directory as the executable. It seems pretty clear to me that you are trying to solve a problem which does not exist.

Comment: I also compiled a simple project with Visual Studio and the exe does not search in the same directory for version.dll . I was wondering if that behavior could  be implemented in Lazarus as well. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: I'm sure that's where it would search first if you linked to it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can define a custom manifest in Lazarus, but for Delphi the solution can be found here:

[How do I avoid dll hijacking in Delphi application that uses WinApi.Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604758/how-do-i-avoid-dll-hijacking-in-delphi-application-that-uses-winapi-windows/76865256#76865256)

Ps: to create a manifest that is compatible with the recent versions of Delphi, please see this resource:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Customizing_the_Windows_Application_Manifest_File